# How much does "integrated graphics" reduce system performance & stability?

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, cpu, crash

I'm a programmer running Win 10 Pro 64-bit with 16gb RAM. My current laptop is my first without a dedicated graphics chip and also by far the least stable. I don't play games and don't need a high-end graphics chip for my usage, it was more when PCs had only 2gb or 4gb memory, I was always wary of "sharing" memory with the graphics processor.

My previous machine maxed out at 8gb and ran Windows 7 Pro. It occasionally froze up or had memory issues but they were rare. Now I run Win 10 with 16gb and I get Out of Memory errors and weird behavior all the time. Driving me nuts!

To be fair, I usually have 2 IDEs open (client app & server backend), a Slack/Discord client, 100-200 Chrome tabs, and various utilities. Without a doubt, web pages are much more bloated in 2020 than in 2017 or so, so keeping those tabs open definitely chews up more memory today. When there's a memory issue, killing some memory-intensive tabs in Chrome's Task Manager is usually enough to reclaim enough memory to compile my program again, but only for a while. Memory usage is *always* high, as I write this Task Manager stated memory consumption is 81% even though my user profile is only 6.2gb.

With all of that said... I can't help but think that a dedicated graphics card with its own memory, which left the CPU and system memory alone, would increase system stability and reduce the memory issues I'm having. This is a laptop so I have no way of retro-fitting a graphics card, my decision is really for determining whether to make a dedicated graphics chip mandatory when I buy my next laptop. Any insight is appreciated. Thanks.

[Task Manager image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llVw3.png)

Comment: Integrated graphics are fine.. they might not be using system ram to function (check).  You have 16gb of ram. You should NOT be getting out of memory errors for any reason.  Stuff gets weird if you have ZERO page file.. but aside from that.. you should be fine.  I had visual studio, intelliJ, android studio, ultraedit, outlook, slack, and zoom (+countless other things) all running today without a problem on a fairly crappy dell i7 laptop with 16GB.  I was debugging between visual studio and a VM in android studio.  You should have no problems with the setup.  If so, its something else.

Comment: "My current laptop is my first without a dedicated graphics chip and also by far the least stable"   <-- That may not be because of integrated graphics. My (now gone) T61P with discrete graphics had its issues and was not readily upgradeable. My X230 (this machine) and my X1 both with Intel integrated graphics are both remarkably stable and upgradeable.

Comment: @John "That may not be because of integrated graphics" yes I understand they may not be correlated, that's why I'm asking. There also Win 7 vs Win 10, web pages eating more memory, etc

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas "You should have no problems with the setup. If so, its something else." That's why I thought perhaps the lack of dedicated graphics was contributing. I have memory problems regularly, I'm also on a dell laptop (i5) with 16gb, running similar programs. I'm constantly looking at Task Manager to find the top CPU and Memory use, plus Chrome's Task Manager. Very frustrating.

Comment: Have you disabled the swap file?

Comment: After answering @Mokubai question, if the answer is that you still have a swap file.. you are going to need to be creative to figure this out.  SysInternals Process Explorer is a nice tool.. it can show you things that nothing else does.

Comment: @Mokubai I have a 14+ GB pagefile.sys, I believe that's the swap file.

Comment: I do appreciate the comments you've left. Just been frustrated with this computer for a long time. @SeñorCMasMas let me ask another question... currently TaskManager reports 83% Memory used when only about 7 GB of in use by my programs (image added). I get that there are system processes and all that but 6-7 GB? Does your Windows use that much memory for non-user processes?

Comment: If you aren't a video game programmer, you should be fine. That said, Chrome is an insane memory hog. 100-200 tabs is way too many. Close them as you finish using them. Even with Firefox I will periodically close the program if I've had many tabs open or a dynamic page open for a long time (re: a single youtube playlist open for hours) as it will regularly chew through 2-3 Gb of memory.

Comment: @Casey "you should be fine" <-- but I'm clearly not. Hence the question. I agree Chrome (or more accurately, certain poorly written, or ad-intensive, web sites) is a memory hog. But even if Chrome is using 4, 5, 6 gigs... the machine has 16gb of memory, I'd expect there would be plenty left. But no...

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to mention some points.

- Win7 vs Win10: While Windows7 only has one service pack, Windows 10 has multiple versions. Your best bet is to install one of the newest ones (I avoid the latest one, because they always seem to be buggy - after a while, cumulative updates solve the bugs).
- Integrated GPU memory usage: I'm not sure exactly how much memory an integrated GPU can use - if you'd like to reduce memory & CPU usage though, you can disable some visual candy (transparency effects in particular).
- Did you say your user profile needs 6.2GB of RAM to run on idle? I would consider 3GB to be a lot, and I've never seen 6GB for idle. What's using your RAM when you aren't doing any work? Disable some services and background programs.
- Chrome eating memory? Try updating Chrome to see if there are any improvements. You can also play with chrome's flags. I'm not gonna tell you to shut down your tabs, because I'm sure you need all of them :D
- Simply putting a dedicated GPU inside your computer would not solve system instability - unless there's something wrong with your integrated GPU's drivers - try to update ALL drivers, actually (if you're not gonna reinstall a newer Win10 version).

P.S. To actually answer the question in the title: Instability shouldn't be a  problem when using integrated - it can hurt your computer and CPU's performance though - but if you're only doing some programming/browsing, you shouldn't really notice it I think.